# Cannot create capfile and deploy.rb using capistrano for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

After I create a new app using :

```
rails new app
```

and after I install the gems for capistrano I then go to the app root folder and I type :

```
cap install STAGES=production
```

And that's gives me this message :

```
mkdir -p config/deploy
[skip] config/deploy.rb already exists
[skip] config/deploy/production.rb already exists
mkdir -p lib/capistrano/tasks
[skip] Capfile already exists
Capified
```

Although it says the deploy.rb, the production.rb and the Capfile that they exist, I cannot find none of them, also the directories it says it created it isn't there either.

**Update**

I'm at the root directly of my new app, and when I type :

```
ls config
```

I get :

```
application.rb  credentials.yml.enc  environments  locales     routes.rb
boot.rb         database.yml         importmap.rb  master.key  storage.yml
cable.yml       environment.rb       initializers  puma.rb
```

And when I type :

```
ls config/deploy
```

I get :

```
ls: cannot access 'config/deploy': No such file or directory
```

and when I type :

```
ls lib/capistrano/tasks
```

I get :

```
ls: cannot access 'lib/capistrano/tasks': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I mean the logic for that is just `if File.exist?(entry[:file])\nwarn "[skip] #{entry[:file]} already exists"` - it's really not possible for those files to not be there. How are you checking whether the files exist?

Comment: @smathy I checked both through the file explorer and through 'ls' in the terminal in the root folder of the app

Comment: ...and how are you running the `cap install`? Also through terminal in the same folder? Like what I'd really like to see is a copy/paste of that terminal session, showing the `cap install` and the output about the files already existing, and an `ls` of one of those paths showing the shell doesn't think they exist.

Comment: Please post output of `ls config`, `ls config/deploy`, and ls `lib/capistrano/tasks` from the root of the Rails root directory. Those might be in the `.gitignore` file, causing your editor (VSCode, SublimeText, Atom) to hide those files because they aren't committable. If they are there, you can remove from `.gitignore` and commit them.

Comment: @Unixmonkey sorry for the late reply, but I edited the post to add the contents of the folders you mentioned

Comment: @smathy it's exactly the way I wrote it in the post, I just type "cap install STAGES=production" and then I get the above massage I mentioned.

Comment: Which versions of rails and cap?